# How to describe time "offset"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

My friends and I are in different time zones, so I'm trying to say,

> We have a 10 hours time offset

Is that right for this situation ? If not, what's the right replacement of `offset` here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Time difference* seems to be adequate.

Comment: +1 for the right replacement word although Barrie when I hear time difference I imagine that the first one is setting off 10 hours earlier before the second one. So he should use two sentences. *My friends and I are in different time zones. We have 10 hour time difference*. Is there something wrong of my point of view ?

Comment: And since "hours" already implies time, you can just say "we have 10 hours difference"

Comment: @speedyGonzales: either *a 10 hour time difference* or *10 hours time difference*.  But I think *my friend and I have a 10 hour time difference* is comprehensible without further explanation.

Comment: @speedyGonzales: I think it will usually be apparent whether there is a plus or minus time difference. Where it isn't, you can say something like 'you're 10 hours ahead of us' or 'you're 10 hours behind us'.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would say *The difference between our time zones is 10 hours*.